# Ruby openssl lib - Why does AES-256-CBC decrypting gives readable data without the correct IV?

Tags: ruby, openssl, aes

Given the following script

```
require "openssl"
require "securerandom"

key = SecureRandom.random_bytes(32)
iv = SecureRandom.random_bytes(16)

aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")
aes.encrypt
aes.key = key
aes.iv = iv

crypted = aes.update("a"*50)+aes.final

aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")
aes.decrypt
aes.key = key
aes.iv = iv

puts aes.update(crypted)+aes.final

aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("AES-256-CBC")
aes.decrypt
aes.key = key

puts aes.update(crypted)+aes.final
```

I get the following output (e.g.):

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
���y��f{�K~:y��aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Does I need to perform these CBC-style XOR operations, block size caring etc. on my own? I cannot find any example which is not simply calling the update function passing the string which should be decrypted. I already tried to add .dup to all string assignments to prevent inplace edit issues. What is going on here?

Environment: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IV's purpose is to prevent discovery of the key by analyzing multiple messages containing the same data. It is not intended to obscure the information if you have the key. Without the proper IV, the first block of the ciphertext will be incorrect, but subsequent blocks will decrypt properly, as you found. The IV protects the key, not the data.

You get the same thing if you perform similar encryption via the openssl command line tools (here I replace the 8-byte IV embedded in the encrypted ciphertext with 8 space character):

```
echo "Ruby openssl lib - Why does AES-256-CBC decrypting gives readable data without the correct IV?" | \
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass pass:password | \
perl -pi -e "s/^(.{8})(.{8})/\1        /" | \
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -pass pass:password

▒▒▒▒▒▒t▒8q▒g] -▒▒▒▒▒▒7<s AES-256-CBC decrypting gives readable data without the correct IV?
```